# Azure Logic Apps, no content from queue

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have the following trigger:

```js
"triggers": {
    "When_there_are_messages_in_a_queue": {
        "inputs": {
            "host": {
                "connection": {
                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azurequeues']['connectionId']"
                }
            },
            "method": "get",
            "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent('drugconsortium-positive-result')}/message_trigger"
        },
        "recurrence": {
            "frequency": "Minute",
            "interval": 1
        },
        "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['QueueMessagesList']?['QueueMessage']",
        "type": "ApiConnection"
    }
}
```

then I try to get messages from queue:

```js
    "Get_messages": {
        "inputs": {
            "host": {
                "connection": {
                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azurequeues']['connectionId']"
                }
            },
            "method": "get",
            "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent('drugconsortium-positive-result')}/messages",
            "queries": {
                "visibilitytimeout": "30"
            }
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "ApiConnection"
    }
```

and then try to send email with queue content:

```js
"For_each_2": {
    "actions": {
        "Send_email_(V4)_3": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": {
                    "from": "email@zzz.com",
                    "ishtml": true,
                    "subject": "message",
                    "text": "<p>want!!!@{items('For_each_2')?['MessageText']}</p>",
                    "to": "receiver@gmail.com"
                },
                "host": {
                    "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sendgrid']['connectionId']"
                    }
                },
                "method": "post",
                "path": "/v4/mail/send"
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "ApiConnection"
        }
    },
    "foreach": "@body('Get_messages')?['QueueMessagesList']?['QueueMessage']",
    "runAfter": {
        "Get_messages": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    },
    "type": "Foreach"
}
```

After execution I see a message for the trigger:

```js
{
  "MessageId": "83aac220-9ee5-440c-9a34-391abaa0e464",
  "InsertionTime": "Thu, 12 Mar 2020 20:21:51 GMT",
  "ExpirationTime": "Thu, 19 Mar 2020 20:21:51 GMT",
  "PopReceipt": "AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAA+JoXDKz41QE=",
  "TimeNextVisible": "Thu, 12 Mar 2020 20:23:09 GMT",
  "DequeueCount": "1",
  "MessageText": "{\"DriverId\":-1,\"DriverName\":\"John Smith\",\"DriverSSN\":\"111-11-1111\",\"CarrierName\":\"Carrier Name\",\"DER\":{\"Name\":\"Der name\",\"Email\":\"werew@zzzz.com\"}}"
}
```

but `Get_messages` has in result:

```
QueueMessage : []
```

and I don't receive any email. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you don't need `Get_messages`, check the trigger definition [When there are messages in a queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azurequeues/#when-there-are-messages-in-a-queue), it will return the `Messages` type, means you already get the message.

Cause the queue is already processed by the trigger the it will be removed from the queue so you could not get it again with the action.

So after the trigger you could get the message content with the dynamic content.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! The topic of Logic Apps + Azure Queues is covered by the docs very poorly, and your post is single most important of everything I could find.

Comment: The crazy thing about it is that Logic Apps are supposedly old, mature product but your post is just 1 month old.